# Perl socket function to connect to SMTP-Server

Tags: sockets, network-programming, perl

I just wanted to write my own Perl script to send emails via the mail server of my ISP. Because I am intrested in the Perl builtin socket-function, I started to experiment with it (I wrote some little tools with IO::Socket already, and I want to improve my knowledge on the builtin one).
My current code:

```
use Socket;
use diagnostics;
my $port = 25;
my $server = "<Servername>";
socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname("tcp"));
my $inetaddress = inet_aton($server);
my $peeraddress = sockaddr_in($port, $inetaddress);
connect(SOCKET, $peeraddress);
my $answer = <SOCKET>;
#sysread(SOCKET, my $answer, 200);
print "Answer was: ".$answer."\n";
print SOCKET "EHLO <domain>\n";
#syswrite(SOCKET,"EHLO <Domainname>\n", length("EHLO <Domainname>\n"));
$answer = <SOCKET>;
print "Answer was: ".$answer."\n";
close(SOCKET);
#shutdown(SOCKET, 1);
```

My problem: I get the first line of the SMTP ("220 [...] ready"). After that it just stops, as if the server did not get the "EHLO"-line from me. After e certain time the connection timeouts, and I get that printed on the screen instead of the expected "250 OK" after my "EHLO".
The commented lines were attempts that did not solve the problem. Any ideas?

EDIT: I know there are some good modules on CPAN, but its for learning and for fun, so this does not help.

Comment: I hope you're aware of https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP and this is fun project.

Comment: You may have to set your socket to auto-flush. One way is with `$|`. Or you may look into `IO::Handle` or, better, `IO::Socket`.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to use those modules, my goal was to build it with the builtin function. Now I set the $|-variable on 1, and nothing changed.

Comment: try \r\n instead if \n as specified in the RFC for SMTP.

Comment: `Socket` is a Core module, just like `IO::Socket` is. But if you insist on not using its convenience, i can only suggest to look into Wireshark or something similar to see if you actually did send your response. And if you sent it to the correct address (both ip- and MAC-) and port. Only then can one say where the problem really is.

Comment: If you did `$|=1` and changed nothing else, you've set `stdout` to auto-flush. Try with `select((select(SOCKET),$|=1)[0]` if you *really* don't want to use `IO::Handle`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Socket;

my $port = 587;
my $server = "smtp.live.com";
my $inetaddress = inet_aton($server);
my $peeraddress = sockaddr_in($port, $inetaddress);
my $answer;

socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname("tcp"))
    or die "Can't open socket $!\n";
connect(SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in($port, $inetaddress))
   or die "Can't connect to port $port!\n";

print SOCKET "EHLO $server\n";

while ($answer = <SOCKET>) {
    print "Answer was: $answer\n";
}

close(SOCKET) or die "Can't close socket: $!";

__OUTPUT__
Answer was: 220 BLU436-SMTP163.smtp.hotmail.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Ve
rsion: 8.0.9200.16384 ready at  Sat, 24 May 2014 13:19:57 -0700
```